# same target URL for different entries wizard oracle apex

Tags: oracle-apex

I've created a `static list` with 6 steps. I use it for top of my wizard pages .

2 targets for 2 entries are the same page but their sequences are different !
When I'm opening the wizard , those 2 steps are checked together while I'm on a right sequence .

how can I prevent checking them on the same time ?

Comment: add a serverside condition to each one ?

Comment: I did set an Expression for Condition Type based on value of page items but nothing changed. what else can I do ? please help me through this.

Comment: Apologies - you need "Current List Entry" expression - see my answer. Serverside condition will hide step entirely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set an expression on "Current List Entry" > "List Entry Current for Pages Type" on each of the entries that point to the same page. Make sure that the condition is only valid for the current entry.

Example. Suppose there are entries "Step 1" and "Step 2" both pointing to page 1. On page one create a page item P1_WIZARD_STEP that has value STEP1 when user is in first step and "Step 1" needs to be valid. If "Step 2" needs to show, then set P1_WIZARD_STEP to "STEP2". In this case the expression would be
`:P1_WIZARD_STEP = 'STEP1` for entry "Step 1" and `:P1_WIZARD_STEP = 'STEP2` for entry "Step 2".

This is just a sample - the condititions for your pages will probably be different but you'll get the point.